# Load Linux Kernel Module From Memory

Tags: c++, c, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I would like to load a linux kernel module from memory. By memory I mean that the raw bytes (of the module) are stored in form of an array in the program that loads it.

I know this works on Windows, however I did not get it to work on Linux with the `init_module` syscall. Is this even possible with that syscall or are there other options I can try?

Comment: That is exactly what the `init_module` syscall does. If that doesn't work for you, you should add your code to the question. Without that, it's hard to say what could be wrong. Also, don't forget to add your kernel version (`uname -r`).

Comment: Don't forget that `init_module()` sets `errno` if anything goes wrong, and `errno` can help you figure out what went wrong. See: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/init_module.2.html

Comment: Nevermid I got it to work. The vm I was testing it on had a kernel update, and was incompatible with the version I built it on. Thank you :)